# Cant run foreach loop on laravel collection, Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, laravel, collections, foreach

I am looking to pass in a collection of Board objects into my view. However, it fails on the for loop inside the blade template.

This is the route to the view

```
Route::get('board', function () {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $board = Auth::user()->boards()->where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
    $boardColumns = $board->columns()->get();
    return view('pages.kanban', compact('user', 'board', 'boardColumns'));
});
```

This is the result of dd method

```
Collection {#299 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
     0 => BoardColumn {#300 ▶}
     1 => BoardColumn {#301 ▶}
     2 => BoardColumn {#302 ▶}
     3 => BoardColumn {#303 ▶}
```

Finally, this is the for each loop

```
        @foreach($boardColumns as $column)
            <li class="drag-column {{ $column->slug }}">
                <div class="drag-column-header">
                    <h2>{{ $column->name }}</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="drag-options" id="options{{ $loop->iteration }}"></div>
                <ul class="drag-inner-list" id="{{ $loop->iteration }}">
                    @foreach($column->tasks as $task)
                        <li class="drag-item"></li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>

            </li>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: fails in what way? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @MarkBaker Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:

Comment: I hope the error is on  the second foreach $column->tasks. It may not be an array. Can you print the full data

Comment: @manian you were right... I completely forgot about that... thanks!

Comment: Great, I hope your issue gets resolved soon. Happy coding :)